# Overflow menu is not showing in Actionbar

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I spend a lot of time to show overflow menu(three dots) in action bar but i can't show it. my java code is

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_type, menu);
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.mapTypeNone:
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;

        default:
            break;      
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

map_type.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Normal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Satellite"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Terrain"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Hybrid"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="None"/>

</menu>
```

and manifest.xml is

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

               </application>
```

please tell me what should i do to create overflow menu in action bar which is not showing from me. please help me.

Comment: you must be testing on a device which have a physical (hardware) menu button. If you test it on device having no hard menu key then it will be shown as overflow option.

Comment: If it testing device has physical menu button then can we show overflow option at action bar or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this little hack here:

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if(menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Ignore
}
```

Good place to put it would be the onCreate-Method of your Application class.

It will force the App to show the overflow menu. The menu button will still work, but it will open the menu in the top right corner.
As of Android 4.4, the ... affordance in the action bar will be there, regardless of whether the device has a physical MENU button or not. Google's current Compatibility Definition Document now comes out a bit more forcefully against having a dedicated MENU button.

Answer (score 0):

try changing in menu layout file from 
android:showsAction="never"  to 
android:showsAction = "ifRoom".

Hope this helps you..

Comment: thanx .
But my issue has resolved by adding the code given in previous comment.